# Can.t Access View Controller Methods of VC Created By instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier

Tags: ios

I have a root UIViewController that has its NSManagedObjectContext var set by AppDelegate (iOS8 app coded using Swift).

The root controller(the master view of a splitview controller) has a button whose action presents another UIViewController with the following code segment:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("addGeometricEntityContent") as! UIViewController
vc.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I get a compiler error as follows:
'UIViewController' does not have a member named 'managedObjectContext' for the line of code:

```
vc.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContextas a test
```

I tried adding a simple testPrint() function to the presented UIView Controller as a test and got a similar complaint that vc instance does have a method testPrint()

Is the vc instance created by storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier somehow different from a fully instantiated object?

If I remove the line

```
vc.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext
```

the code works as expected and presents the UIViewController instance.

Answer (score 0):

The application delegate object is accessible from everywhere, so you could write in your view controller

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to correct the problem by down casting the UIViewController type to my specific controller type as follows:

```
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("addGeometricEntityContent") as! AddGeometricEntityContentViewController
```